# How to Pivot/Unpivot Something with SQL2000

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2000, ssrs-2008

I'm querying a table which essentially a bunch of dates.

```
FRECDCUST              DTRECDCUST              DTINSPECTED             DTRECDCUSTPO           DTADDEDSO                 DTSHIPPEDSUP                  DTQUOTEDCUST
1/1/1900 12:00:00 AM    7/27/2010 12:00:00 AM   7/30/2010 12:00:00 AM   7/26/2010 12:00:00 AM   8/6/2010 12:00:00 AM    1/1/1900 12:00:00 AM    8/6/2010 12:00:00 AM
1/1/1900 12:00:00 AM    7/27/2010 12:00:00 AM   7/30/2010 12:00:00 AM   7/26/2010 12:00:00 AM   8/6/2010 12:00:00 AM    1/1/1900 12:00:00 AM    1/1/1900 12:00:00 AM
1/1/1900 12:00:00 AM    1/1/1900 12:00:00 AM    1/1/1900 12:00:00 AM    1/1/1900 12:00:00 AM    1/1/1900 12:00:00 AM    1/1/1900 12:00:00 AM    1/1/1900 12:00:00 AM
1/1/1900 12:00:00 AM    1/1/1900 12:00:00 AM    1/1/1900 12:00:00 AM    1/1/1900 12:00:00 AM    1/1/1900 12:00:00 AM    1/1/1900 12:00:00 AM    1/1/1900 12:00:00 AM
1/1/1900 12:00:00 AM    1/1/1900 12:00:00 AM    1/1/1900 12:00:00 AM    1/1/1900 12:00:00 AM    1/1/1900 12:00:00 AM    1/1/1900 12:00:00 AM    1/1/1900 12:00:00 AM
1/1/1900 12:00:00 AM    3/12/2010 12:00:00 AM   3/15/2010 12:00:00 AM   3/11/2010 12:00:00 AM   3/16/2010 12:00:00 AM   3/24/2010 12:00:00 AM   4/13/2010 12:00:00 AM
1/1/1900 12:00:00 AM    11/6/2009 12:00:00 AM   11/6/2009 12:00:00 AM   11/3/2009 12:00:00 AM   11/9/2009 12:00:00 AM   11/20/2009 12:00:00 AM  12/7/2009 12:00:00 AM
```

I am taking the date difference between two dates on each line. For example, the days to inspect is found like this:

```
SELECT (CASE
          WHEN year(SYC_ext.DTRECDCUST) <> 1900
               AND year(SYC_ext.DTINSPECTED) <> 1900
          THEN
            DATEDIFF(dd, SYC_ext.DTRECDCUST, SYC_ext.DTINSPECTED)
          ELSE
            NULL
        END)
         AS [AverageDaystoInspect]
Blah blah...
```

This creates a row of different DateDiff calcuations which end up looking like this:

```
Product Class   Average Days to Inspect Average Days to Process SO  Average Days to Ship to Affiliate   Average Days to Quote   Average Days to Receive Ammended PO
01  2   4   8   27  21
01  2   4   8   27  21
01  3   5   2   88  8
01  3   5   2   88  8
01  1   8   11  72  1
01  3   2   7   27  0
01  5   2   7   27  0
```

Please forgive the spacing problems.

So, each of these rows in the data set starts with a number which represents a product category in this case 01 and is followed by a series of day calculations.

I can average these values and give you an average for each category per product class. However, they want the day calculations along the left side of a table or matrix with the product classes along the top, exactly opposite of what I have here. If I pivot them in Excel, I get the following:

```
                          01    05     10
Avg Days to Inspect       5      3      5
Avg Days to Process PO    4      5      5
Avg Days to Ship          20     18     19
```

I hope this makes sense. Any idea how I can perform this in SSRS or t-sql?

Comment: would this help? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410.aspx

Answer (score 0):

This will do it, assuming that you can load the data from your first query into a intermediate temporary table:

```
DECLARE @t TABLE
    (
      ProductClass INT
    , InspectDays INT
    , ProcessDays INT
    , ShipDays INT
    )

INSERT  INTO @t
        SELECT  1
              , 2
              , 4
              , 8
        UNION ALL
        SELECT  1
              , 4
              , 5
              , 2
        UNION ALL
        SELECT  5
              , 2
              , 4
              , 8
        UNION ALL
        SELECT  10
              , 3
              , 5
              , 2

SELECT  'Avg Inspect'
      , [01] = AVG(CASE WHEN ProductClass = 1 THEN InspectDays
                   END)
      , [05] = AVG(CASE WHEN ProductClass = 5 THEN InspectDays
                   END)
      , [10] = AVG(CASE WHEN ProductClass = 10 THEN InspectDays
                   END)
FROM    @t
UNION ALL
SELECT  'Avg Process'
      , [01] = AVG(CASE WHEN ProductClass = 1 THEN ProcessDays
                   END)
      , [05] = AVG(CASE WHEN ProductClass = 5 THEN ProcessDays
                   END)
      , [10] = AVG(CASE WHEN ProductClass = 10 THEN ProcessDays
                   END)
FROM    @t
```